# Choosing Key and IV in AES-256

Tags: cryptography, aes, random, initialisation-vector, key

I am working on a real-life project for a firm. I have to encrypt data using AES 256 as per specification. I want to know how are the key and IV are really chosen in real world projects. /dev/urandom is good enough for both? Any other advice regarding these?

Comment: i would feed 32+bytes of random into SHA3-256, which outputs an AES256-sized key. the SHA3 part distributes the entropy evenly around the bytes and makes it harder to guess, unless your random is really really broken instead of just sub-optimal.

Comment: @dandavis Thanks. Makes sense. Also, how do I ensure that IV is always unique? Do I store and always check? What's the right way?

Comment: a cropped SHA-3 of the datetime should produce a different IV each time it's called (IVs need not be secret)

Comment: @dandavis They also need to be unpredictable. That is very predictable. The correct answer is to use a CSPRNG.

Comment: @LukeP: the "need" is not universal, it depends on the mode: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17044/when-using-aes-and-cbc-is-it-necessary-to-keep-the-iv-secret i don't like modes where the iv needs to be a secret, but they do exist. that said, i don't see how an RNG prevents iv-reuse without storage, both of which can present un-needed complication/risk. Using sha3 makes it safe and easy to concat some urandom with the timestamp and please everyone.

Comment: Why not just random IV? If you get a collision there, you have MUCH bigger problems already (crappy implementation or crappy RNG).

Comment: @dandavis I feel like you might misunderstand. The IV does not need to be, nor did I suggest that it should be, secret, just unpredictable. It is considered best practice to use a CSPRNG when generating IV's. I've never seen anyone hash a timestamp and use it as an IV.

Comment: @LukePark: thanks. the part i'm confused about is how can something be unpredictable if it's not secret?

Comment: @dandavis Unpredictable given any prior IVs from prior messages.  E.g. the next IV of the next message can be predetermined if it is the hash of a timestamp.  With a CSPRNG, this is not the case.  Secret =/= unpredictable.

Comment: @LukePark: the crypto rabbit hole gets deeper, i got homework to do...

Answer (score 1):

All that is necessary is that the values are random and unique. It is perfectly acceptable to pull them from your operating system's cryptographic random API or from a crypto library like OpenSSL that contains its own internal cryptographically secure random number generator (CSPRNG).